# Need help in wiring two Peltier Plates together

Tags: peltier

I have two of the BXQINLENX 55x55MM 7V 1.25A TEG1-241-1.4-1.2 Thermoelectric Power Generation Peltier Modules.

I am trying to make something like an Ecofan by sandwiching them between one aluminum plate and a heat sink. I need urgent help as the deadline of my project is approaching fast. Should I connect them in series or parallel? I mean should I lay them side by side and connect each of their red wire to a red wire or connect their red and black together? I eventually want to power a fan and hopefully a USB device with them by using a step up module. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072JC5PFC) is the one I have.

I am not noticing much of a change in output with two Peltier and similar results are with just one Peltier tile only. I know I am doing something wrong.

Also, can I use [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008O0Y2Y8) product to join the aluminum parts or will that affect the functionality of the project?

I have two of the following heat sinks, should I use both to create a greater temperature difference?

1. [First](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073VDVVP5) heat sink.
2. [This](https://m.newegg.com/products/N82E16835856005?ignorebbr=true&source=googleshopping&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-Mobile&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-Mobile-_-pla-_-CPU+Cooling-_-N82E16835856005&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1sfinKeQ4AIVsxx9Ch3MdA7IEAQYDiABEgLiV_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) second heat sink that I have is without a fan but I have attached a fan to it.

Sorry if this questions are very basic but I don’t have an engineering background. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial video on how to make a thermoelectric generator by using Peltier Modules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaT2hqHgLdY.

Comment: That silicone sealant is more of an insulating material.  It will  **impede** the transfer of heat.  You won't want to use it anywhere that heat has to move from one part to another.

Comment: [Related.  Maybe duplicate.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26625/teg-in-series-require-power-balancer-align-adapter)

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Regarding the sealant can I use it on the sides of peltier tiles? I mean just to join the aluminum parts and not in between the sandwich area of the peltier tiles or is that not a good idea either?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you will need to do is find out how much power your device needs. The peltiers need to generate more power than the load consumes. So if you need 1W for a fan, the petlters better be able to generate 1W. You need more voltage than the load needs. If it's a 5V fan then the peltiers need to be able to go up to 5V.

The second thing is you need a *temperature gradient* (or temperature drop across the peltiers) This means one side should be hot and one side cold. [Use this datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwi2yamZm5HgAhUTEXwKHShUBJMQFjADegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fthermoelectric-generator.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F04%2FSpecTEG1-12611-6.0Thermoelectric-generator1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Lomxob9LlZ-FmUR3irTxh) to find out how much the temperature drop. The datasheet also shows how much power you can generate. I'm not going to go into further explication, because I'm willing to bet this is an academic exercise and some work needs to be done by you. 
[image]

If you have a with the hot side at 50C and the cool side at 30C, you'll have 0.5V with a matched load (~1Ohm). If you want 3V, you'd need the hot side to be at 200C and the cold side to be at 30C. These peltiers are not the best to use if you want voltage.

If you connect the peltiers in series, and they will generate twice as much voltage than one peltier alone. If you connect them in parallel they will generate twice as much current.

Use thermal paste with a low thermal conductivity to connect the peltiers to the heatsink.